# How do I make strikethrough text programatically in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I know I can do this in MXML:

```
<s:CheckBox label="Some Text" lineThrough="true" />
```

But how can I do the same thing programatically? The following doesn't work:

```
var newCheckBox:CheckBox = new CheckBox;
newCheckBox.label = "Some Text";
newCheckBox.lineThrough = "true"; // Flex code help doesn't see "lineThrough"
dummyContainer.addElement(newCheckBox); // Just some dummy container to add the element to.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955"
               minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import spark.components.CheckBox;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var checkBox:CheckBox = new CheckBox();
                checkBox.label = "Some text";
                checkBox.setStyle("lineThrough", true);

                addElement(checkBox);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks :)
It sure does explain a lot as well.

Comment: The Flex pre-compiler adds a lot of magic - MXML properties don't always equate to class members.  If you cannot resolve a MXML attribute, check style properties.  Also, add the "-keep" compiler argument to keep generated ActionScript if you need to see how the mxmlc compiler has translated your MXML documents to ActionScript.

Comment: Thanks for the added info; it has been invaluable. I'll definitely do that!